# Is it possible to @mark.parametrize twice one test?

Tags: python, testing, pytest, fixtures, parametrized-testing

I have multiple functions which `raise ValueError` to test. So far my solution is:

```
import pytest
import record

@pytest.fixture(name='raised')
def is_value_error_raised(func, args):
    try:
        func(*args)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


@pytest.mark.parametrize(('func', 'args', 'expected'),
                         ((record.check_length, ('Test', 1, 100), True),
                          (record.check_length, ('', 1, 100), False),
                          ))
def test_length_check(raised, expected):
    assert raised == expected


@pytest.mark.parametrize(('func', 'args', 'expected'),
                         ((record.check_lang_code, ['EN'], True),
                          (record.check_lang_code, ['Test'], False),
                          ))
def test_lang_check(raised, expected):
    assert raised == expected
```

but in this approach I am repeating function name in each test case. I try to get rid of it. I was wondering if is it possible to make something similar to:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(('func', record.check_lang_code))
@pytest.mark.parametrize(('args', 'expected'),
                         ((['EN'], True),
                          (['Test'], False),
                          ))
def test_lang_check(raised, expected):
    assert raised == expected
```

This produces `ValueError`. Is there a way to use two parametrize markers working with each other? If not how can I correct this code?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by mapping test function with tested element inside fixture. Anyway I still wonder if it is possible to achieve same effect using double parametrization. Other, more elegant solutions will be really appreciated.

```
import pytest
import record

@pytest.fixture(name='raised')
def is_value_error_raised(request, args):
    try:
        test_name = request.node.function.__name__
        {'test_length_check': record.check_length,
         'test_lang_check': record.check_lang_code,
        }[test_name](*args)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


@pytest.mark.parametrize(('args', 'expected'), (
        (('Test', 1, 100), True),
        (('', 1, 100), False),
))
def test_length_check(raised, expected):
    assert raised == expected


@pytest.mark.parametrize(('args', 'expected'), (
        (['EN'], True),
        (['Test'], False),
))
def test_lang_check(raised, expected):
    assert raised == expected
```